# Lazy Loading not working, related entity is always null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I Have a problem with the EF. 
The realated entity is always null. I didn't get any solutions so far.

Here are the models:

```
 public class Categories
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AtpID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubCategories> SubCategories { get; set; }
 }

 public class SubCategories
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string LinkToProducts { get; set; }
  }
```

So, every Categorie has more subcategories.
In the Seed method I populated the database, so I have data:

```
var categories = new List<Categories>
        {
        new Categories{Name="Abgasanlage", ID=1},
        new Categories{Name="Elektrik",ID=2},
        new Categories{Name="Filter", ID=3},
        new Categories{Name="Karosserie", ID=4},
        new Categories{Name="Kuhlunkg",ID=5}
        };

        categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var subCategories = new List<SubCategories>
        {
        new SubCategories{Name="Montageteile", ID=1, CategoryID=1},
        new SubCategories{Name="Lamdasonde",ID=2, CategoryID=1},
        new SubCategories{Name="Anlasser", ID=3, CategoryID=2},
        new SubCategories{Name="Luftfilter", ID=4, CategoryID = 3},
        new SubCategories{Name="Ohlfilter", ID=5, CategoryID = 3},
        new SubCategories{Name="Sonstige", ID=6, CategoryID = 4},
        new SubCategories{Name="Wasserpumpe", ID=7, CategoryID = 5}
        };

        subCategories.ForEach(s => context.SubCategories.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Altought it seems that evrything is ok, the related entity is always null, even with the Include(), is null.

I tried this way:

```
Models.Categories entity = db.Categories.Where(m => m.ID == 3)
                                   .Include(m => m.SubCategories)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

but entity.SubCategories is always null.

with Include also the related entity is null

```
var setting = (from s in db.Categories.Include("SubCategories")
                           where s.ID == 3
                           select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

[image]

In my project I have more related entities, where the lazy loading is working.

Only with these models (Categories and SubCategories) I have the problem.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on your `SubCategories` model.You have to fix that as shown below.

**Note :** use `public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }` on it.Hence you didn't do that,EF doesn't know how to fetch the related entities (or navigational property) from the db when you use `Include` or Lazy loading.And also you need to change `CategoryID` as `CategoriesID`.B'cos your model's name is `Categories`.

```
public class SubCategories
 {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoriesID")]
    public virtual Categories Categories{ get; set; }//you have to do this
    public int CategoriesID { get; set; }

    public string LinkToProducts { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: It seems that I resolved my problem, by changing the foreign key in SubCategories model, from CategoryId to CategoriesID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class SubCategories
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public Categories Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string LinkToProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the navigation property in `SubCategories` class:

```
public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }
```